# Correction for Multiple Comparison of Means - Tukey HSD in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, statsmodels, posthoc, tukey

I have a dateset with 4 conditions (A, B, C, D). What I observed running a One-Way Anova is that there is a linear increase of my dependent variable (Reaction Time, RT) in the 4 conditions.

I would like to run a post-hoc test to see if the increases of RT from A to B, from B to C, and C to D are significant with a Tukey HSD post-hoc test.

To run the test in Python, I am using the following code:

```
#Multiple Comparison of Means - Tukey HSD
from statsmodels.stats.multicomp import pairwise_tukeyhsd
print(pairwise_tukeyhsd(df["RT"], df['Cond']))
```

The problem I am facing is that here it is assumed that I am interested in all possible comparisons (A vs B, A vs C, A vs D, B vs C, B vs D, C vs D). Thus, the correction applied is based on 6 tests. However, I am only making hypothesis on 3 comparisons (A vs B, B vs C, C vs D).

How can I inform the post-hoc test about the number/type of comparisons I am interested in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot. Tukey HSD is not like your pairwise t test with a multiple comparison adjustment on the raw p-values. The p value you see is based on [the studentized range (q) distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey%27s_range_test).

One way you can do this is to fit a linear model, which is like your anova, and you do a pairwise t-test on the coefficients, and subset on those that you need.

To illustrate this, I use some simulated data, this is what TukeyHSD would look like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
from statsmodels.stats.multicomp import pairwise_tukeyhsd
from statsmodels.stats.multitest import multipletests

np.random.seed(123)

df = pd.DataFrame({'RT':np.random.randn(100),'Cond':np.random.choice(['A','B','C','D'],100)})

hs_res=pairwise_tukeyhsd(df["RT"], df['Cond'])
print(hs_res)

Multiple Comparison of Means - Tukey HSD, FWER=0.05
===================================================
group1 group2 meandiff p-adj   lower  upper  reject
---------------------------------------------------
     A      B  -0.6598 0.2428 -1.5767 0.2571  False
     A      C  -0.3832 0.6946 -1.3334  0.567  False
     A      D   -0.634 0.2663 -1.5402 0.2723  False
     B      C   0.2766 0.7861 -0.5358 1.0891  False
     B      D   0.0258    0.9 -0.7347 0.7864  False
     C      D  -0.2508 0.8257 -1.0513 0.5497  False
---------------------------------------------------
```

Now we do ols, and you can see it is pretty comparable :

```
res = ols("RT ~ Cond", df).fit()
pw = res.t_test_pairwise("Cond",method="sh")
pw.result_frame

    coef    std err t   P>|t|   Conf. Int. Low  Conf. Int. Upp. pvalue-sh   reject-sh
B-A -0.659798   0.350649    -1.881645   0.062914    -1.355831   0.036236    0.352497    False
C-A -0.383176   0.363404    -1.054407   0.294343    -1.104528   0.338176    0.829463    False
D-A -0.633950   0.346604    -1.829032   0.070499    -1.321954   0.054054    0.352497    False
C-B 0.276622    0.310713    0.890281    0.375541    -0.340138   0.893382    0.829463    False
D-B 0.025847    0.290885    0.088858    0.929380    -0.551555   0.603250    0.929380    False
D-C -0.250774   0.306140    -0.819147   0.414731    -0.858458   0.356910    0.829463    False
```

Then we choose the subset and method of [correction](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.multitest.multipletests.html?highlight=multipletesting), below I use simes-hochberg like above:

```
subdf = pw.result_frame.loc[['B-A','C-B','D-C']]
subdf['adj_p'] = multipletests(subdf['P>|t|'].values,method='sh')[1]
subdf

    coef    std err t   P>|t|   Conf. Int. Low  Conf. Int. Upp. pvalue-sh   reject-sh   adj_p
B-A -0.659798   0.350649    -1.881645   0.062914    -1.355831   0.036236    0.352497    False   0.188742
C-B 0.276622    0.310713    0.890281    0.375541    -0.340138   0.893382    0.829463    False   0.414731
D-C -0.250774   0.306140    -0.819147   0.414731    -0.858458   0.356910    0.829463    False   0.414731
```

As a comment, if you see a trend there might be other models to model that, instead of relying on a posthoc test. Also subsetting on the test you need and performing a correction can be argued as some type of cherry picking.. If the number of comparisons (like in your example 6), I suggest you go with the Tukey. This is another discussion you can post on cross-validated.

Comment: Very nice! Could you now plot this in a graphical view with matplotlib??

Comment: And, also, how can we add letters showing the difference between the variants?